# Isometries of the Plane, Euclidean space $R^3$ and isometries of the Platonic polyhedra.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, isometry

I want to study the isometries of plane, Euclidean space, and the platonic polyhedra. I am new to this topics.
Can any one suggest books that contain these topic with details and basic explanation through algebraic approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest "Regular Polytopes" from H.S.M. Coxeter.
It even deals with $\mathbb{R}^4$ and beyond.

--- rk

Comment: sir it's not available on any website!

Comment: Well, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Polytopes_(book), the Wikipedia recension. In the notes given there you find a link next to the author (Coxeter) which directs you to the Google books. That page then provides an online preview of most of its pages… - Or just buy that book.